# while updating snapshot data is not working exactly right in my code swiftui

Tags: list, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

The contents of redDates will be displayed in red, and the contents of yellowDates in yellow, and the hours other than these will be displayed in green. This works correctly but during instant update it works when changing from green to yellow, from yellow to green but not updating instantaneously when switching from red to others I have to refresh the page.

```
.background(redDates.contains(hour) ? Color.red: yellowDates.contains(hour) ? Color.yellow: .green)
```

```
struct DateView: View {
    @StateObject var stadiuminfo=StadiumInfoFromUserModel()
    
    var firestoreDatabase=Firestore.firestore()
    var currentUser=Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    @StateObject var daysInfo=dayArrayForUser()
    @State var chosenDay=""
    @State var preDay=""
    @State var yellowDates=[String]()
    @State var redDates=[String]()
    @State var redHours=[String]()
    @State var yellowHours=[String]()
    @State var selectedField=""
    @State var shown=false
    @State var hourType="Full"
    @State var checkInfos=false
    
    var didChange=PassthroughSubject<Array<Any>,Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Group{
                ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack{
                        ForEach(daysInfo.daysArray,id:\.self){day in
                            Button(action: {
                                chosenDay=day
                                getDatefromCalendar(day: chosenDay)
                            }, label:{
                                    Text(day)
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
                                    .background(chosenDay==day ? Color.red: .white)
                                })
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
            }
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Text("Müsait değil").scaledToFill()
                        //.padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.33, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05)
                        .background(Color.red)
                    Text("Müsait").scaledToFill()
                        //.padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.33, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        //.border(Color.black, width: 2)
                    Text("Onay Bekliyor").scaledToFill()
                        //.padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.33, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.05)
                        .background(Color.yellow)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
            if chosenDay=="" {
                VStack {
                    Text("Lütfen tarih seçiniz.")
                }
            } else {
                List(hourType=="Full" ? stadiuminfo.workingHour: stadiuminfo.workingHour2,id:\.self){ hour in
                    NavigationLink(destination: RequestAppointmentView(numberField: selectedField, selectedDate: chosenDay, selectedHour: hour)){
                        Button(action: {
                           
                        }, label: {
                            Text(hour)
                                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.7)
                                .padding()
                                .background(redDates.contains(hour) ? Color.red: yellowDates.contains(hour) ? Color.yellow: .green)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                        })
                    }.disabled(yellowDates.contains(hour) ? true: redDates.contains(hour) ? true: false)
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }.onAppear{
            daysInfo.days()
            stadiuminfo.getDataFromInfoForUser()
            checkInfo()
            getDatefromCalendar(day: chosenDay)
        }
        .navigationTitle(Text("Tarih ve Saat Seçimi")).navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                    Button(action: {
                shown.toggle()
                })
                                {
                Image(systemName: "info.circle.fill").resizable().frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .sheet(isPresented: $shown) { () -> FieldInformationsView in
                        return FieldInformationsView(fieldname:selectedField)
                    }
            }
            )
    }
    
    func getInfos(){
        let fb=Firestore.firestore()
        
        fb.collection("FieldInformations").document(chosenStadiumName).collection("Fields").document(selectedField).addSnapshotListener { (document, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let hourtype=document?.get("HourType") as? String {
                    hourType=hourtype
                }
                //fiyat ve kaporaları çekip listede gösterebilirsin
            }
        }
    }
    
    func checkInfo(){
        let fb=Firestore.firestore()
        
        fb.collection("FieldInformations").document(chosenStadiumName).collection("Fields").addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if snapshot?.isEmpty == true {
                    checkInfos=false
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        if document.documentID==selectedField {
                            checkInfos=true
                            getInfos()
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getDatefromCalendar(day: String){
        
        if preDay != day {
            redDates.removeAll()
            yellowDates.removeAll()
            self.firestoreDatabase.collection("Calendar").document(chosenStadiumName).collection(selectedField).whereField("AppointmentDate", isEqualTo: day).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        if let status=document.get("Status") {
                            if status as! String == "Onaylandı." {
                                let redhours=document.get("Hour")
                                if self.redDates.contains(redhours as! String) {
                                } else {
                                    self.redDates.append(redhours as! String)
                                }
                            }
                            else if status as! String == "Onay bekliyor." {
                                let yellowhours=document.get("Hour")
                                if self.yellowDates.contains(yellowhours as! String) {
                                } else {
                                    self.yellowDates.append(yellowhours as! String)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.didChange.send(redDates)
            self.didChange.send(yellowDates)
        } else {
            redDates.removeAll()
            yellowDates.removeAll()
            self.firestoreDatabase.collection("Calendar").document(chosenStadiumName).collection(selectedField).whereField("AppointmentDate", isEqualTo: day).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        if let status=document.get("Status") {
                            if status as! String == "Onaylandı." {
                                let redhours=document.get("Hour")
                                if self.redDates.contains(redhours as! String) {
                                } else {
                                    self.redDates.append(redhours as! String)
                                }
                            }
                            else if status as! String == "Onay bekliyor." {
                                let yellowhours=document.get("Hour")
                                if self.yellowDates.contains(yellowhours as! String) {
                                } else {
                                    self.yellowDates.append(yellowhours as! String)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.didChange.send(redDates)
            self.didChange.send(yellowDates)
        }
    }
    
}
```

In this code, whichever color I get for the head, this time it is not updated instantly from that color to the others.

Comment: We don't know what `redDates`, `hour`, `yellowDates`, etc are or how you're updating them. Could you update your code to get as close to a [mre] as possible?

Comment: You haven't shown where `getDatefromCalendar` exists and how it relates to `background(`. I *assume* it's in an `ObservableObject` and the arrays are `@Published` properties, but if that were true, you code would probably work. You haven't shown enough code yet to demonstrate the issue. Check out the link I used before.

Comment: almost all of my codes. but what I mean is that in the first code it updates from yellow to red instantly but not from red to yellow or green (ie to the next ones). But when red and yellow are swapped, the same thing happens for yellows this time. @jnpdx

Comment: I've never seen a design pattern quite like this in SwiftUI. I'm not sure what the `PassthroughSubject` is supposed to be doing here, since you're already updating `@State` properties. If it were my code (some users here may disagree), I'd move all of the async Firebase code into an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties for the arrays.